# Connect to MySQL Server from node.js, but server in remote loaction

Tags: mysql, node.js

Connect to MySQL Server from Node.js But MySQL Server in remote location, How can i connect?

I tried below example :

```
   var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"http://somelocation", 
    user:"root",
    password:"roor"
});

connection.connect(function(err){
   if (err) {
    console.log("Error Connection to DB" + err);
    return;
   }
   console.log("Connection established...");
});

connection.end(function(err){


});
```

But I am getting Error :

```
Error Connection to DBError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://exmaple.com
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you have to open port for mysql in remote machine. also use hostname without `http://`

Comment: The name of the DBMS is "MySQL", not "SQL DB". And no, you don't interact with MySQL using HTTP. It has its own protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to estimate connection without set protocol type in hostname field:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"somelocation.com", 
  user:"root",
  password:"roor"
});
```

In docs I see only this case for hostmane field: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql